# Redirect in IIS 7.5/8 with regular expression

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url, redirect, iis

I need to redirect a lot of URLs like the following

```
http://localhost/OmniService/foto/18443151-810079.jpg
```

so, in my web.config I set the following regular expression:

```
<rewrite>
    <providers>
        <provider name="DB" type="DbProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
            <settings>
                <add key="ConnectionString" value="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RewriteDB;Integrated Security=True;Server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=working2014" />
                <add key="StoredProcedure" value="RewriteDB.dbo.GetRewrittenUrl" />
                <add key="CacheMinutesInterval" value="0" />
            </settings>
        </provider>
    </providers>
    <rules>
        <rule name="DbProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(OmniService/foto/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
            <!--<conditions>
                <add input="{DB:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>-->
            <action type="Redirect" url="(Omniservice/foto/2017/02/02/18443151-810079.jpg)" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it's not captured, despite testing with IIS says it's ok:
[image]

If I use `<match url="(.*)" />` then I am redirected to the corrected new URL but nothing is showed anyway because it says there were too many redirects.

Answer (score 1):

The rule works for me, but it redirects me to http://localhost/(Omniservice/foto/2017/02/02/18443151-810079.jpg) maybe you need to remove () from url attribute in action node? Do you not even see a 301 redirect with above rule?

Comment: Useless. This is what I get now: `HTTP ERROR 500` I have also tried with a FileMapProvider instead of a database one but...nothing. The url is always the old one, it's not redirected,